# Amazon Web Services - S3 - Logstash or Lambda to channel data into Elasticsearch?

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-s3, logstash, aws-lambda

My question would be a pro/con one. I want to channel data from an Amazon S3 to Elasticsearch, and am considering two options: Channeling through Logstash or via Lambda. Which one would be the faster/easier/more resilient solution and why? Has anyone any experience?

Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure about the lambda tag? It is more about lambda in a programming language than the Lambda Amazon service

Comment: Well, it is called Lambda, though I understand the confusion.

Comment: The lambda tag is explicitly about lambda in programming languages. So the lambda tag in your question is misleading. And there is a tag [aws-lambda](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aws-lambda)

Comment: Thank you, will update accordingly. Any chance you can add something valuable regarding the question itself?

Comment: I'm writing an answer, mostly about Logstash

Comment: Thank you! :) I've edited the post acording to your suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Disclaimer:** My experience is only with Logstash.

With logstash you have to deal with the server, with the logstash installation and configuration. But you don't have to write any code and you have plugin ready to deal with the connections.
And if you don't have modify the data the configuration is very straightforward. If you have modification Logstash has a various plugin to do different operations.
[Logstash documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/introduction.html)

From what I read about aws-Lambda, you won't have to manage a server and an application, but you'll have to write all the code, including the connection to the S3 and Elasticsearch.

Answer (score 1):

So far AWS Does not support custom logstash service modules.  so like you said, we have two ways:

- logstash
  pros:
  You can make use of all logstash functionality and filters
  Popular standard tool for logs shipping
  cons:
  You need to setup and EC2 machine that runs the logstash agent.
- Lambda function
  Pros:
  no server setup is needed, I also believe there is no additional cost.
  cons:
  You will need to write the code for reading from S3 and writing to ElasticSearch

I have also come across this lambda function that does this standard shipping.
https://github.com/arithmetric/lambda-stash

looks promising but doesn't seem to support logstash filters

Comment: Looked at lambda-stash.  While well intentioned, it slurps input files entirely into memory before sending the 1st document to ES.  Also, the handlers add little value over the node modules they wrap.  I.e. it's only 1 pipe() call to gunzip a zipped stream.   Same goes for CSV parsing the input.  And so on.   If, for some reason, logstash won't do what you need OOTB, I'd recommend just rolling your own Lambda using Node modules directly.  Less code, easier to read and trouble-shoot and, most importantly, correct stream handling.